# Php | Given html string, how can I extract a src attribute?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the src attribute of an html iframe string in php.

```
$iframe; /* This is my iframe variable, initialized above. (Just here for demonstration) */
/* I want to get the src attribute of this iframe html */
```

Comment: Huh? PHP is a server side language. Iframes are client side. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: ...regex be like...

Comment: @Rooster Erm, you mean [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) right? You don't use regex to parse html..

Comment: @ChipDean Don't be lazy, read the question :)

Comment: show us a var dump of your `$iframe`



`var_dump($iframe);` and post result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this.

```html
preg_match('/src="([^"]+)"/', $iframe, $match);
$url = $match[1];
```

Comment: What is the $match variable?

Comment: $match is the variable you store the result of the preg_match in. If a match is found ofcourse. More info on preg_match can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php